# Devise: Redirect authenticated users to a single subdomain in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, subdomain

I have a Rails 5 app that uses Devise for user authentication and currently shares the user session across the primary and sub domain.

I would like to change this behavior so that authenticated users are routed to the subdomain `sub.example.com` while non-authenticated users are kept on the primary domain `example.com`.

The solutions I've found are focused around multi-tenant implementations, however this is not a multi-tenant app and I only need to redirect users to a single subdomain at this point.

I am currently using a custom Devise method to redirect authenticated users to the requested resource as determined by his or her role:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if current_user.try(:guest?)
    documents_path
  else
    stored_location_for(resource) || dashboard_path
  end
end
```

Is this something that would be handled with an additional application controller filter or perhaps another way?

Comment: for `documents_path`? `documents_url(host: "sub.example.com")` — note that you'll need to use `_url` and not `path` to get the `host` key to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks.  This would be for all authenticated paths.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok to override the devise method, however you probably wanna move it to your application_controller where you will have access to Rails path helpers

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if current_user.try(:guest?)
      documents_path
    else
      stored_location_for(resource) || dashboard_path
    end
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
    #send them somehwere
  end

end
```

Then you will need something like this in `config/initializers/session_store.rb`

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, domain: '.maindomain.com'
```

Or if you only want sessions for one specific subdomain:

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, domain: 'something.rootdomain.com'
```

Comment: This code is currently in my application controller, I just need an approach to handle the subdomain routing on login/logout.

Comment: see updated answer, you need config in session_store.rb